# winui 3 How to create a data model (class) for DataTemplate in c++?

Tags: xaml, winui-3

WinUI3 c++/winrt
I have a DataTemplate in App.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SomeViewTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding val1}"/>
        <RatingControl MaxRating="{Binding val2}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

And I want to create a GridView in MainWindow.xaml like this:

```
<GridView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SomeViewTemplate}" >
    <GridView.Items>
        <local:SomeModel val2="5" val1="vvdfbdb" />
        <local:SomeModel val2="3" val1="sdgdfshbdsh" />
        <local:SomeModel val2="5" val1="dhbdshfdf" />
    </GridView.Items>
</GridView>
```

What should the structure of SomeModel look like for everything to work?

In c# it can be done like this:

```
public class SomeModel 
{
    public string val1 { get; set; }
    public string val2 { get; set; }
}
```

How to do the same in c++?

Comment: You need to add the Midl File. If you want to realize the DataTemplate and GridView control via c++. I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [Tutorial: Create a simple photo viewer with WinUI 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/get-started/simple-photo-viewer-winui3?tabs=cpp)